# Passing functions + corresponding parameters, as parameter to another function , while number of parameters for passed functions vary

Tags: python

I am passing a function (and it's corresponding parameters) as parameters to another function.

The problem is, I do not know how to handle when the number of parameters required for each passed function varies.

This is very hard to explain, so here's an example

```
def method1(a): #Not an option to change
    return a

def method2(a1, a2): #Not an option to change
    return a1 + ' ' + a2

def method3(methodToRun, params):
    result = methodToRun(params[0], params[1])
    return result

method3(methodToRun = method2, params = ['hello world', 'bye world'] )
```

method3 can take in a function, and the function's corresponding parameters, which will vary. For example, method1 will only take in one parameters, but method2 will take in two parameters.

I do not know how to set up method3 so that it can handle executing either method1 or method2 while providing their parameters. It is currently only set up to take in method2, but not method1.

Rewriting method1 and method2 is Not an option, because in my case,  those methods belong to library that I can Not alter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments). For example:

```
def method3(methodToRun, *args):
    result = methodToRun(*args)
    return result
```

Then you can call `method3` as bellow:

```
method3(method2, 'hello world', 'bye world')
method3(method1, 'hello world')
```